# Can I use lookup for elem in a list full strings

Tags: haskell

A function that receives a list of strings and any string that contains a question mark, appends the string of : For example to [ "1 1?","2.","ab?","c."] result ["F:1 1?","2.","F:ab?","c." "] are calculated.

```
    import Data.Char

    data StringList = NilSL
            | ConsSL String StringList

    f2 [] = if elem "?" [] == True then "F:" : [] else False
```

Comment: What is your question.

Comment: something in the Code was wrong so i get an error. how i can write another coder or what have i to Change in this ode so i get what i want to?

Comment: Start by writing the type for `f2`

Comment: My probelm was with this "elem" I have to us for this Code. How I use elem and can append a string before the string where this question mark was?

Comment: I know, i only want to know how I can use it, an example that I can see what i made wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you put an empty argument to your function.

Then you don't have to write if(smthg == true) but just if(smthg).

Then you have to use recursivity. Write ["F :" ++ x] (x bing a [char] use ++ instead of ':' )

you concat that with recursive (f2(xs)). Finally f2 [] = [] when you finish your list

```
import Data.Char

data StringList = NilSL
    | ConsSL String StringList

f2 [] = []
f2 (x:xs) = if elem '?' x then ["F:" ++ x] : f2 (xs) else [x] : f2 (xs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)) I understans everything you explai here